# Showing that $Y := |\sum_{n\geq1}X_n|$ converges with Borel-Cantelli lemmas

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of i.i.d rv's with distribution  $P(X_n=\frac{1}{n})=P(X_n=-\frac{1}
{n})=\frac{1}{2}$ We need to show that $Y := |\sum_{n\geq1}X_n|$ converges a.s.
It is also noted that $E[|Z|]\leq E[Z^2]^\frac{1}{2}$ might be usefull. How do we use the Borel-Contelli lemma's to show this?

Comment: Not iid. You could build on your previous question rather than answering the same a second time...

Comment: Also why to put absolute values in the expression in the title ?

Comment: It was a typo there should be absolute value signs

Comment: @Olivier I asked it a second time because that theorem is not part of my course so there should be another way

Comment: Use the ideas in the proof of the two series theorem for your proof

Comment: I don't see how I could use $E[|Z|]\leq E[Z^2]^\frac{1}{2}$ there

Comment: The basic idea is to use Kolmogorov inequality - which is not exactly related to Borel Cantelli lemma. If not in your course, it is not clear how to proceed.

Comment: I asked about the absolute value because the convergence holds without, so it seems a bit weird to have one here.

Comment: @Olivier If I try to use the two series theorem we have $|\sum_{n\geq 1}X_n|\leq \sum|X_n|$ but $E[|X_n|]=1/n$ and it's sum, the harmonic, series diverges. So we can't use that?

Comment: Expected value of $X_n$ is $0$, and variance of $X_n$ is $1/n^2$, which is summable. Kolmogorov inequality then allows to enhance the L^2 convergence of the series to an almost sure convergence.

Comment: Yes but we need to check if  $|\sum_{n \geq 1}X_n|$ converges instead of  $\sum_{n \geq 1}X_n$

Comment: Take a moment to think about your last comment please

Comment: @Olivier sorry I mean if $\sum X_n<\infty$ does not implies $|\sum X_n|<\infty$ because  we could have $\sum X_n$ diverges to $-\infty$

Comment: @Olivier But I solved it sorry for bothering you :( Might be another one comming today haha